# Show name of employers instead time in highcharts

Tags: graph, highcharts

How to show "name" for each column instead time/months in highcharts?
Take a look:

http://jsfiddle.net/B7rGw/

In the bottom of each columns are displayed months, but I want to display names. Ex: Joe, Hanna, Billy, Jhon...

```
$(function() {
    $.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-v.json&callback=?', function(data) {
        // create the chart
        chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                alignTicks: false
            },
            rangeSelector: {
                selected: 1
            },
            title: {
                text: 'AAPL Stock Volume'
            },
            series: [{
                type: 'column',
                name: 'AAPL Stock Volume',
                data: data,
                dataGrouping: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            }]
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For HighStock (that is the chart you are linking to) it is implied to always be a time-based xAxis.

If you want to have names on your xAxis what you need is a category-based [graph](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-basic).